# Run anonymous apex as if it were a test case

Tags: apex, unit-test

Is there any way to run anonymous apex so that it is treated the same way as a unit test?

Sometimes it would be ideal to just try some code out and know that any DML operations that get performed won't be committed. I wouldn't expect callouts to occur or emails to be sent.

This would also allow individual test methods to be run from a class. So if one method in a dozen or so is failing you could re-run it and get a more concise log.

I have considered using transaction control and just doing a rollback, but that doesn't give the full advantage of running as a test.

Comment: Related - Ideas: [Allow single test method execution from an Apex Class](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007YDC)

Comment: As a support rep for an ISV I'd love this more than anything! The ability to run a block of code and not worry about affecting production data would be a huge troubleshooting tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a complete answer but you can always rollback dml operations yourself:

```
System.Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try {
    //all you anonymous code
} catch(DmlException e) {
    System.debug('DmlException='+e);
} finally {
    Database.rollback(sp);
}
```

You will still have the problem of callouts and emails being sent, but if these are not a factor it will be sufficient

Comment: Thanks. I had considered using transactions. And as you say, this gives some of the advantages of running as a test.

Answer (score 4):

As of vesion 0.22.81, the [force cli](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/forcecli) supports running anonymous apex in a test context by wrapping it in a temporary class and using [compileAndTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest.htm):

```
$ force apex -test
>> Start typing Apex code; press CTRL-D(for Mac/Linux) / Ctrl-Z (for Windows) when finished
Test.startTest();
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
System.assertEquals(3, accounts.size(), 'number of accounts');
Test.stopTest();

>> Executing code...
ERROR: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: number of accounts: Expected: 3, Actual: 152
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if they based that off my post - [Using the Salesforce Metadata API to run a single test method in isolation](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/06/using-salesforce-metadata-api-to-run.html)

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment about using the metadata api on the Idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another method similar to Daniels is to just throw an arbitrary exception at the end of your script; This will have the same effect and roll back the whole transaction.

The difference is that since mailouts are queued, but not sent until the end of a successful transaction, the uncaught exception will cause Salesforce to cancel sending the mail queue.

for example

```
doStuffHere();
throw new NullPointerException();
```

Answer (score 1):

As a stub answer assuming no one has a way to do this or something equivalent I've raised the following idea: [Run anonymous apex as if it were a test case](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000inJZAAY)

When I have previously tried to run test cases from anonymous apex I get the error:
"System.TypeException: Cannot call test methods in non-test context"